# RXTX how to send and read data from comport

Tags: java, rxtx

I'm new to **rxtx** library i just want to know how to **send** data and **recieve** data from com port using rxtx and i'm a ***window's*** user.

Comment: What have you tried? This is very basic and extensively covered in documentation and tutorials that is easily found through google.

Comment: Also please read this, http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/ to know how to form good questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can start to look on [read from COM](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=11) and [serial port communication](http://codeglobe.blogspot.ro/2009/02/serial-port-communication-in-java.html). A library for this is jSSC.